# MySQL Workbench - Export recordset to an external file - SQL inserts contain blank table names

Tags: mysql, export, workbench

When I run a query from a query tab and it returns results, I hit the resultset icon option to "Export recordset to an external file".

I then select save as type "SQL INSERT statements" then click save

An Export options popup asks me what Table Name to use and it is prepopulated with the name of the table I am currently exporting from. I then click Export.

The file is exported properly and everything looks ok except the table name is not populated:

```
INSERT INTO `` (`name`,`value`) VALUES ('instate_lastrun',NULL);
INSERT INTO `` (`name`,`value`) VALUES ('instate_lastrun','201089524');
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Using latest Workbench 8.0.19 CE Community 64bit on Win10

Comment: I think that is a bug. I am also having the same issue with this version. The earlier versions of MySQL workbench don't have this issue.

Comment: the version now is 8.0.21 give it a try, or else report a bug

Comment: I just upgraded to lastest 8.0.21 and the same problem remains

Comment: Still experiencing the same issue. I can't be the only one?

Comment: You are not the only one and unfortunately I just manually patch it everytime myself smh

Comment: Issue persists :(